# how to let user choose the mail receiver?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

in my app i used the code below to handle the messages send from iphone i want to know how to let him **choose between contact us and tell a friend** like other apps how can i make this issue ?

the code :

```
-(IBAction)sendEmail {
    //Create a new mailComposer object and set the mailComposeDelegate (required).
    MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {

        //Set Fields such as Subject, recipients, and message body.
        [mailComposer setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"info@Myweb.com",nil]];
        [mailComposer setSubject:@"App Feadback"];

        //Present the mail view controller
        [self presentModalViewController:mailComposer animated:YES];
    }

    //release the mailComposer as it is now being managed as the UIViewControllers modalViewController.
    [mailComposer release];
}

//MFMailComposeControllerDelegate method that handles success or failure
//and dismisses the mailComposer
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error 
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    if (result == MFMailComposeResultFailed) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Message Failed" message:@"Your message failed to send" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Contact Us, you have to prefill your mail address to mailComposer.setToRecipient. as you have done.

And for tell a friend, you have to collect your friend's email address prior the mail composer in view. e.g. using Address book person picker control.

Whatever you do, MFMail composer will not allow you to do anything without the knowledge of the user. The user can delete/add in the mailto field when it pops up.

Comment: hello i mean can i use this code but when the user touch the button send mail a half window appear tell friend or contact us then according to the choose he made i will fill this code (info@...com) or (plus sign == add mail address) in the receiver filed

Comment: You can use a UIActionSheet to pop up such a half window with option buttons.